# Can I configure VSCode to use PS1 editor for "file / new" in stead of TXT?

Tags: powershell, default

Can I configure VSCode to use **PS1** editor for "file / new" in stead of TXT ?

I only use VScode for Powershell and do not want to have to perform "ctrl+K M Powershell" every time I create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Press F1 and then type "Open Settings" and click on "Open Settings(JSON)".
In the opened file, add a new line `"files.defaultlanguage": "powershell"` and make sure you add a comma on the line above, so after each line, at the and there is a comma.

Then save the file and you are done.

Example File:

```
{
    "powershell.codeFormatting.useCorrectCasing": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "powershell.codeFormatting.autoCorrectAliases": true,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "files.defaultLanguage": "powershell"
}
```

Open Settings:

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

In settings (UI), look for "defaultlanguage" and fill it with "powershell":

[image]

Or set it in the settings JSON:

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "powershell"
```

Look [here for reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_how-do-i-set-the-default-language-for-new-files)